# How to enable QtScript in your project when using MS Visual Studio compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2010, qtscript

With QMake, the setup for QtScript is as simple as adding this to your `.pro` file:

```
QT += script
```

But we'e using MS Visual Studio for the project. What do I change to make Visual Studio recognize includes for QtScript? Currently, it reports that the files were not found:

```
#include <QScriptEngine>
#include <QScriptValue>
```

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '`QScriptValue`': No such file or directory

I use the Qt add-in for visual studio. I have checked the script option there - well actually it **was checked already** - but that didn't solve the problem:

[image: image description]

Comment: use the vs addin that will set the paths for you; else you will need to set your additional include paths, additional library paths and additional dependencies for the QtScript module

Comment: @Zaiborg I have the add-in. In the project settings, I have checked "*Script*" entry. That has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like you, same error. Then I tried to include like this:

```
#include <QtScript/QScriptValue>
```

And it worked. **I tried this again** :

```
#include <QScriptValue>
```

And now it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't seem so far to work: `Cannot open include file: 'QtScript/QScriptEngine': No such file or directory`. I will try to clean and rebuild, but I think it won't help.

Comment: Weird... Did you include the QtScript directory in `Additional Include Directories` under your project properties?

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is something similar to what is explained in [this](http://www.saoe.net/blog/715/) link,

To summarize,

Configuration properties: General
Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set

C/C++: General
Additional Include Directories: "QT include directory here".

Linker: General
Additional Library Directories: "QT Lib directory here".

Linker: Input
Additional Dependencies: Qt5Core.lib Qt5Gui.lib Qt5Widgets.lib (the import libraries for the required Qt DLLs) 
(Add subscript d for debug mode ...)

Comment: This is general setup for Qt. I have already Qt working, but QtScript isn't available by default.